# React: How to use setState inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. I read an article that suggests us to use functional component instead of class that extends React.Component, so I followed. I also use the arrow function instead of function keyword. That is:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {...}
```

I got a structure that has 20 properties like:

```
{
    id: '',
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '', 
    ...
}
```

I am using if ... else if ... to set the state, but I saw some examples that use this.setState() in just one line of code. I try to import setState from 'react', but fail.

Is there a way to use setState() instead of setName(), setId(), ..., etc? Or any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 9):

There is only the (one) 'setState()' method - not a method per-property (as you've suggested/questioned).

It is a composite in terms of it's parameter, in that you can specify/set more than one item within the same/one call (to the 'setState()' method), so you can set all 20 of your items in one go.

E.g.

```
  this.setState({ "firstName" : firstNameVal, "lastName" : lastNameVal });
```

I was starting from where you said you started - from a 'class' based component.

If you are sticking with the switch to a 'function' based component, then it is slightly different, in summary:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

...

// The 'useState' hook (function) returns a getter (variable) & setter (function) for your state value - and takes the initial/default value for it/to set it to, e.g.
const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState('');
```

And you then use the getter var to read it & the setter function to set it:

```
  setFirstName('Dennis');
```

(I could be wrong but I believe 'hooks' were added in v16.8 of React.)

A more in-depth description:

[https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/reactjs-tutorial/reactjs-state#:~:text=1%20A%20state%20can%20be%20modified%20based%20on,merge%20between%20the%20new%20and%20the%20previous%20state](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/reactjs-tutorial/reactjs-state#:%7E:text=1%20A%20state%20can%20be%20modified%20based%20on,merge%20between%20the%20new%20and%20the%20previous%20state)

Comment: I got: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. At first, I though it is because I use fat arrow function. Then I change to use the function keyword, but the error still appear. I am working on to change it to class that extends React.Component. And hope that will get better. Thank you.

Comment: I was starting from where you said you started - from a 'class' based component.

If you are sticking with the switch to a 'function' based component, then it is slightly different, in summary:

`
import React, { useState } from 'react';

...

// The 'useState' hook (function) returns a getter (variable) & setter (function) for your state value - and takes the initial/default value for it/to set it to, e.g.
const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState('');
`

And you then use the getter var to read it & the setter function to set it:

`
    setFirstName('Dennis');
`

Answer (score 7):

Use `useState` hook in functional components.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ first: "hello", second: "world" });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={state.first} onChange={(ev) => setState({...state, first: ev.target.value})} />
      <input type="text" value={state.second} onChange={(ev) => setState({...state, second: ev.target.value})} />
    </div>
  )


}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

this.setState only works in class based components. In functional components [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook is used which behaves as a state

useState lets you add React state to function components.

Answer (score -1):

Class-based components and functional components both have different ways of storing and setting values in them.

In class-based components, **this.state** is used which is usually of an object nature and holds all the values needed in the components, here **setState()** function is used to do a **shallow update** to this.state object. (It will merge the prev and new object)

In function-based components state can be stored using **useState** hook. The name of the state variable can be anything. Just like the class component here, we have two items returned by the useState hook. The **first item represents the variable** and the **second represents the setter function**.

Now,

To useState variable is declared like,

```
const [banana, setBanana] = useState("initial value - could be string, number, object");
```

To use the variable in the component just use the variable name "banana" and set a new value in the variable using the setter function like,

```
setBanana("good banana");
```

This will change the initial value to whatever you set it to. If the variable was an object, it will be **replaced by the new object not shallow merged**.

Also, inside a function-based component, you can have any number of useState variables. The important thing to keep in mind is if multiple of them are called in a function call **batching** is performed.

Refs:-

1. https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate
2. https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable