# How do I replace this.setState when using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I'm trying to convert my class component to a functional component using React Hooks.
I'm not sure what to do with this code snippet:

```
this.setState({
      pinError: !isValidPin,
      pin: updatedPin,
    });
```

I was thinking of maybe deleting it completely? This is what I have so far:

```
const PinInput = ({pinError, pin, isInputActive}) => {

    const handleValidatePinDigit = (e) => {
        const isValidPin = isValidPinDigit(e.target.value);
        const updatedPin = isValidPin ? e.target.value : '';

    this.setState({
      pinError: !isValidPin,
      pin: updatedPin,
    });

    if (get(updatedPin, 'length', '') === 4) {
      onComplete(updatedPin);
    } else {
      onChange(updatedPin);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: You can use useState hook and initialize your states with something like `const [pinError, setPinError] = React.useState(!isValidPin)` and later use the corresponding functions to update the respective states!

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to use setState inside functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65733906/react-how-to-use-setstate-inside-functional-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you understand how to initialize, set and use state using the useState hook. Please read comments too.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


// pinError & pin are deconstructed state passed down and are used as the initial values of your pinError & pin state
const PinInput = ({pinError, pin}) => {

    const [newPinError, setNewPinError] = useState(pinError); // initialize state
    const [newPin, setNewPin] = useState(pin);

    const handleValidatePinDigit = (e) => {
        const isValidPin = isValidPinDigit(e.target.value);
        const updatedPin = isValidPin ? e.target.value : '';

        setNewPinError(!isValidPin); // set state 
        setNewPin(updatedPin);       
    };

    // this printPin function shows how to use state 
    const printPin = () => {
        if (newPinError) { 
            console.log("[pinError] Your invalid pin is: " + newPin);
        } else {
            console.log("Your valid pin is: " + newPin);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I get '"PinError' is missing in props validation" for the one in--> const PinInput = ({PinError, Pin}) => {

Comment: I changed your code from 'pinError' to 'PinError' to show you the difference. Whatever you deconstruct must match exactly what's being passed down. I would change it back to 'pinError' and rename the hooks if it gets confusing.

Comment: Same thing for the 'pin'

Comment: Even when all of them are lowercase I get "Identifier 'pinError' has already been declared"

Comment: that's because your state name matches exactly with the prop that's being passed down. You can't have variables with the same name. I'll edit my code example to help you out.

Comment: try noticing the difference now. I renamed the state so that it doesn't match the deconstructed state that was passed down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const[pinError, setPinError] = useState(true);
 const[pin, setPin] = useState('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook to achieve your goal.

Try:

```
const [pinError, setPinError] = useState(false);
const [pin, setPin] = useState('')

setPinError(!isValidPin)
setPin(updatedPin)
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this.setState function.
Try like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';



const PinInput = ({pinError, pin, isInputActive}) => {

     const [pinError, setPinError] = useState(pinError);
     const [updatedPin, setUpdatedPin] = useState('');
    const handleValidatePinDigit = (e) => {
        const isValidPin = isValidPinDigit(e.target.value);
        const updatedPin = isValidPin ? e.target.value : '';
        setPinError(!isValidPin);
        setUpdatedPin(updatedPin);
    if (get(updatedPin, 'length', '') === 4) {
      onComplete(updatedPin);
    } else {
      onChange(updatedPin);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: actually, now I get that: Identifier 'pinError' and 'pin' have already been declared because I use them here: const PinInput = ({pinError, pin, isInputActive}) => {

Comment: I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: Where did you declare values name as pinError and pin,

Comment: Could you share code on codesandbox please?